# Multiple many_to_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Multiple many_to_many relationships - Admin functionality

I have a composer has_many[collections, categories, styles]

A composer's membership in a collection, categories, styles is updated the through a page of checkboxes for each has_many

So should I have my own custom restful routes/methods, such as update_collections, update_categories. And manually inside each of these methods implement the logic to reconcile what is saved/updated in the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

if the collection, categories, styles do not themselves have properties for composer.. just delete_all categories and insert new relationships..